# Git Bash Jekyll site could not be built

Tags: github, command-line, jekyll, github-pages, git-bash

I'm very new to github pages and jekyll but I'm trying to start up my own personal website using them and every time I try to execute '$ bundle exec jekyll serve' it says 'Configuration File: none' even though there's a _config.yml file in the local directory. Along with this I get several other errors keeping me from reviewing my work (posted below). Any suggestions/solutions? myWebsite is the parent folder and jekyllRepo is the jekyll Repository that the _config.yml file and several others are in.

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: none
Source: C:/Users/Owner/myWebsite
Destination: C:/Users/Owner/myWebsite/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating...
 Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in jekyllRepo/_posts/2019-03-03-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.
GitHub Metadata: Error processing value 'title':
Liquid Exception: No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository. in /_layouts/default.html
         ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                ------------------------------------
                No repo name found. Specify using PAGES_REPO_NWO environment variables, 'repository' in your configuration, or set up an 'origin' git remote pointing to your github.com repository.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided a link to your repository, I'll make some assumptions based on your terminal output.
Therefore, this is going to be a trial and error answer.

You may have a Gemfile with `gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins`
or it may contain

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'github-pages'
end
```

Either ways, move `github-pages` out of the `:jekyll_plugins` group. That is, you should have just a bare listing:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'github-pages'
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the repository link. (https://github.com/eingram00/jekyllRepo). My only gem file is actually outside of the jekyll repository and just in the root website folder on my PC. I'm not quite sure how to display the difference in files on my PC versus whats on the repository. (https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll) heres the website I've been using to set up my website.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, simply try removing the `group: :jekyll_plugins` declaration. (on line 18 https://github.com/eingram00/jekyllRepo/blob/6e01e7c11a3a11a48615a5f31ee4286714cc44e9/Gemfile#L18 in your Gemfile in the given repo.)

Comment: This definitely helped and I made it work in the end. What one of the issues for the _config.yml file was that it was inside the jekyllRepo folder and not the parent folder, so basically I just dragged and dropped it into the parent folder and that registered. I still have a lot of work to do but this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First you should verify you have Jekyll and Bundler gems installed with

```
$ jekyll -v
```

you should see

```
jekyll 3.8.5 -- Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator in Ruby
```

if it's not installed, install with

```
$ gem install jekyll bundler
```

If it's install you just need to use the *jekyll* (not the bundle command) command in the root of your website

```
$ jekyll serve
$ jekyll build
```

and yeah, i find the *getting started* on the site a bit confusing as well...

Comment: Oddly enough my jekyll version is only 3.7.4 however I still have the same error message occurring even after making sure I have that downloaded.

Comment: I'm using git bash and attempting to use 'bundle exec jekyll serve' to preview my site

Comment: you didn't read my post :)  don't use 'bundle'  just use 'jekyll'  it works for me under git bash.

Comment: I apologize I missed that part. I made it work in the end though. What one of the issues for the config file was that it was inside the jekyllRepo folder and not the parent folder, so basically I just dragged and dropped it into the parent folder and that registered. I still have a lot of work to do but this is a step in the right direction.